# NSNotification addObserver/removeObserver proper methods to place them in

Tags: ios, ios5, nsnotificationcenter

I've seen `NSNotification` addObserver/removeObserver placed in `viewDidLoad`/`viewDidUnload`, `viewDidAppear`/viewDidDisappear`,`dealloc`....

What are the proper methods to use here so things are neat and tidy?

Answer (score 4):

For viewControllers:
I would say in `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidDisappear:`.
The reason is that you care for these notifications as long as your view is "on screen".
Since a view does not need to be unloaded when your view is offscreen `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidUnload` are the wrong locations for (de)registering notifications.

For registering for notification for non views:
In the `designated initializer` and `dealloc`.

Comment: Or even in the init and dealloc functions, since they dont really do anything to the UI itself, putting them in the init dealloc would be better

Answer (score 4):

That depends. Do you only want to receive notifications when your view controller is on screen (then viewWillAppear/Disappear is probably a good choice) or also when the view is not currently active. In the latter case, the init method might be even better suited than `viewDidLoad` (or does it matter for the notification that the view is currently in memory?).

Also note that `viewDidUnload` is not called in all cases (only when the view gets unloaded but the view controller remains in memory – if the view controller is deallocated while the view is loaded, only `dealloc` is called and is the correct place to unregister.